# SQL - Get list of messages as well as a count value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a page that lists messages using the SQL as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM comments $qwhere ORDER BY comment_date DESC LIMIT $qstart,$qlimit
```

How can I also retrieve the number of messages that share the same `comment_number` (this is not the primary key of the table, just a number type column) on a row by row basis i.e.

```
SELECT count(something), * ... FROM comments
```

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Comment: Why downvotes with no explanation?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is such basic stuff, that is covered in any decent tutorial.

Comment: Only if you know what to look for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look like something like this: (EDIT: added variables)

```
SELECT count(comment_number), comments 
FROM comments 
$qwhere
GROUP BY comment_number
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
LIMIT $qstart,$qlimit
```

`COUNT` and `GROUP BY` being the items that do the work.

You might find [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) helpful as well.

Comment: @Chris, let me know if there is anything that you'd like clarified.  Happy to do it.